# Sudoku generator - indexing matrix, testing for repeat value in row/column

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I lie. It's not really a Sudoku generator, but I'm attempting to randomly generate a 5x5 matrix, kind of like a completed Sudoku grid where numbers are not repeated in each row or column. However, I don't need to check if a number is repeated within a box.

```
import numpy as np
from random import randint

def genRandomMatrix():
    matrix = np.zeros((5,5))

    for ix in range(5):
        for iy in range(5):
            u = randint(1,5)    # generate random int to test
            while True:
                if u in matrix[ix][:] or u in matrix[:][iy]:
                    # test if random int already in indexed row or indexed column

                    u = randint(1,5)
                    # if in row/column, try a new random int

                else:
                    matrix[ix][iy] = u
                    # safe to insert random int

                    break

            print matrix

genRandomMatrix()
```

The output only creates a single row before getting stuck:

```
[[3. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
[[3. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
[[3. 1. 2. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
[[3. 1. 2. 4. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
[[3. 1. 2. 4. 5.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Comment: FWIW, this kind of grid is called a [Latin Square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square). You might find [this code I wrote a few years ago](http://echochamber.me/viewtopic.php?t=35771&start=400#p3241917) of interest.

Comment: Add some print statements to see what the code is doing, or use the debugger.

Comment: You will need to come up with a better algorithm. Your current strategy _can_ work sometimes, if you're lucky with the random numbers, but generally it will get stuck before it completes the square because there won't _be_ a number that works. Take a look at the code I linked earlier, but also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking

Comment: There's some good info here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9913139/4014959

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using row and column slicing in `numpy.matrix` wrong.

Change your if statement to this:

```
if u in matrix[ix, :] or u in matrix[:, iy]:
```

---

By the way, this seems more elegant with quick fixes.

```
import numpy as np
from random import randint

def genRandomMatrix():
    matrix = np.zeros((5,5))

    for ix in range(5):
        for iy in range(5):
            while True:
                # random int
                u = randint(1,5)

                # test if random int already in indexed row or indexed column
                if u in matrix[ix, :] or u in matrix[:, iy]:
                    continue
                else:
                    matrix[ix][iy] = u
                    break

            print matrix

genRandomMatrix()
```

Comment: Thanks, I've been a bit rusty with indexing after not having touched matlab for a while. Now I just need to have it reset if it gets stuck with an incompletable square

Comment: Actually you should use a list and remove items one by one instead of using randint. @Marcus Newton